# iOS 11 Document Editor - Is it open for developers?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios11

with the release of iOS 11, something caught my attention, when you open a Document on the Mail app, or take a screenshot, iOS shows up the toolbar for edition on the document/image. Does anyone know if this toolbar is open for us, developers, to use?

Thanks! [Image of a document previewed on Mail app, with an editor bar to edit the document with annotations, text, signature, etc...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCbwY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly (I would *love* to be proven wrong) as of iOS 11.0, it appears to be Apple private API so far.